# SwiftUI toasts not Dismissing

Tags: ios, swiftui, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-queue

I am using the following method to display a toast message

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
Toastmessage = MyToasts(title: "Message Here" , type: .success)
mysettings.showMytoast = true // mysettings is an Environment variable
}
```

Reason I added like this because toast occurs as result of an action (Removing an item from list) and there is a delay to update view from response.

Now the issue is toast is not getting dismissed until i kill the app.
Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should showMyToast = false after a while.

You can do something like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    Toastmessage = MyToasts(title: "Message Here" , type: .success)
    mysettings.showMytoast = true // mysettings is an Environment variable
    
    let closeAfterSecond = 1
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + closeAfterSecond) {
        mysettings.showMytoast = false
    }
}
```